# vector division?

Tags: vectors

I have a question. Given a vector equation such as F = ma, how can we obtain a general expression for m, the mass? If the equation was scalar, this could easily be done by dividing F by a; however, we are dealing with vectors, and, to my knowledge, a vector divided by another vector is not defined in vector algebra. Therefore, how can we obtain a general expression for m?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take vector norms:
$$m=\frac{|F|}{|a|}$$

Answer (score 2):

If the vector $\vec F$ is parallel to the vector $\vec a$ then $m$ is simply the ratio between their norms:
$$m=\frac{|\vec F|}{|\vec a|}$$
If they are not parallel, then no scalar $m$ can satisfy this equation.

You can better understand this by thinking of the equation $\vec F=m\vec a$ as a system of 3 equations (if we're talking about 3 dimensional space), i.e.
$$\begin{pmatrix}F_x\\F_y\\F_z\end{pmatrix}=
m\begin{pmatrix}a_x\\a_y\\a_z\end{pmatrix}$$
as a system of equations that you want to solve of the variable $m$. Since there are 3 equations and only 1 unknown, a solution is not guaranteed to exist.

Comment: When are force and accn. Not in same direction?

Comment: If they are then i think mass varies

Comment: force and acceleration is always parallel. If there is an acceleration in some direction, then there exist a force in that direction. Solution always exist. If you can't find solution to that system, then your dealing with wrong force vector.

Comment: @Salihcyilmaz True. I was answering the general question about vectors.

Answer (score 2):

First, as you and others stated, there is no vector division. The first thing you need to see is that:

If there exist an acceleration in some direction, then there exist a force in same direction. This is one of newtons laws.

If force and acceleration were not in same direction, then we can't find m such that satisfies the equation as yohBS stated.

If you have two vectors, then their magnitude should be equal right?

Let $ma = F_1 $, then we have

$F = F_1 $ which implies $|F| = |F_1|$

Then 
$$|F| = |ma| = m|a|$$
where you simply divide norm of $F$ to norm of $a$.

I think what you missing is that. Think about a box has mass M. This box sits on ground. Then you apply some force F. This force is not parallel to ground. Refer to figure below:

[image]

Here, you can't divide |F| to |a|. This is because acceleration is caused by net force acting on the body. Net force is tangential component of $F$ since other component is balanced by normal force from ground. Then you need to find tangential component in the direction of acceleration. Where you find m by
$$|F_t| = |ma| = m|a|$$